# Android - Custom Array Adapter Not called During In and Out of a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Got stock with this problem for a couple of days now, I have `LaunchpadSectionFragment` as Fragment A, on onClick event another Fragment(`B`) from a separate class is called named `VideoPlayerFragment`that extends `ListFragment` is being called and displayed.

The problem:

When I click Fragment A it opens Fragment B, inside fragment B contains a listView - which is populated by `LoadAllProducts` from database, then in on `onCreateView()` calls a custom array adapter that loads the returned records in the listView. Now sometimes Fragment B is displays a blank screen then if I will go back to the previous Fragment(A) then goes back to B, it displays the ListView. If lucky, then first time Frag B loads, it will show the listView. I've been struggling with this. Thank you for considering.

```
public class CollectionDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {

     public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {

        public  static class LaunchpadSectionFragment extends ListFragment {

                    //onClick event opens another class which 
                    //Extends another Fragment List

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment1, fragMainGroups );
                    transaction.addToBackStack(fragMainGroups);
                    transaction.commit(); 

        }
     }
}
```

**VideoPlayerFragment.java**

```
 public class VideoPlayerFragment extends ListFragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle e){
                super.onCreate(e);

                 productsList = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>();

                 db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getBaseContext());
                 mContext = getActivity();
                 Log.d("Inside", "onCreate");

                 //this task will populate to get Data from database
                 //I checked in logcat and there are rows returned.
                 LoadAllProducts task = new LoadAllProducts();
                    task.execute();


      }

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       //This custom array adapter is not sometimes called, sometimes not
       //It really happens, I not sure with the reason. I also put some displays
       //logs and sometimes it will execute the code, sometimes does not.

       MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(
                mContext, productsList,R.layout.load_groups_activity_listview, FolderNameGroups, selectedId);           
                setListAdapter(adapter);

       }
```

}

Comment: As you use a `AsyncTask` to get the data it's safe to assume that it may not return the data before the `onCreateview()` finishes which would make the adapter to rely on an empty `productsList`. When the task finishes, in the `onPostExecute()` what do you do?

Comment: Yeah! thank you. Made me realize that it is not important to call my custom arrray adapter on `onCreateView` as I did. So what I did, I transfered my the adapter to `onPostExecute()` which the custom array should supposed to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Luksprog, for giving me the hint. To make sure that the Custom Array Adapter will be called inside the `ListFragment`, I have to put my `MySimpleArrayAdapter` inside `onPostExecute()` on my `AsyncTask` to make sure that it will be executed after the `doBackground()`